# How to convert two strings to give you a function name in Python

Tags: python

If you had two strings, like so ->

```
string1 = "get"  
string2 = "Feed"
```

So how would you use these 2 strings to call a function named -> getFeed() ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on where the function is, you can use one of these:

```
globals()[string1 + string2]()
locals()[string1 + string2]()
```

Comment: Or, only as a last resort, `eval(string1 + string2)()` if it can be in arbitrary scope.

Comment: Oh no it's eval! Yes, that would also work. I imagine a responsible answerer would've said something about the importance of sanitizing input if these variables come from some other system, but it's 2am and I'm hungry.

Answer (score 3):

If ImportedLib had your function getFeed(), you'd call it as such:

```
import ImportedLib
getattr(ImportedLib, string1+string2)()
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume the function is located inside foo. Then call

```
getattr(foo, string1 + string2) ()
```